# How to catch the event when a view is shown after returning from another view?

Tags: android, back-button

A simple question I just can't find the answer...

I have view A and B, after clicking on a button on A, B shows up, and at this time if I click the back button on device, A will be shown again. Now I change something in B and hope it would affect A, e.g. setting A's background color via a global variable, so that when the back button is pressed, A's background color changes, how could I do this? What method is fired when A is shown from clicking the back button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to override the `onResume()` method in A. `onResume()` will be fired once A is back to visible.

Then you can implement `onBackPressed()` method in your B, to save the settings you've made via `SharedPreference` or something else. Then retrieve it on A's `onResume()`.

Thus the whole solution will be like:

Acitivty A:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
//blah blah
//Retrieve SharedPreferences or the saved data from B
}
```

Activity B:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//save your data or settings here
}
```

I think the [Activity Lifecycle in Document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) could help you to figure out what is `onResume()` and exactly when it will be fired.

And `onBackPressed()` in [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29).

Also [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should make explicit return from B. So there should be a color chooser and OK button. The button should close activity B and return value for A. Then A will retrieve the value in
*onActivityResult* method.

The back button is not intended to provide result. Therefore if you want the behavior you described. Then when someone chooses color in B activity, save it immediately in Shared Preferences (remember to name the file). Then read in the same preference file in *onResume* method in activity A and set the background accordingly.